# s3cmd sync S3 Error: 403 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I was trying to do

```
C:\Python27\python s3cmd sync -r K:\a\ s3://test-bucket/test/
```

on windows. It gives an error

> ERROR: S3 error: 403(Access Denied):Access Denied

But the problem is on a different machine with same config for s3cmd, I can push any folder. Only difference is it's `linux`. 
Moreover on earlier machine,

```
C:\Python27\python s3cmd ls
```

works fine. Is this a Path problem, then why am I getting access denied? I am logged in as root in both `windows` (1st machine) and `ubuntu`(2nd machine).

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I didn't run the command prompt as administrator. I assumed as I was logged in as admin, it does that automatically.
Access Denied was from my end I am assuming for now.